# Visualising layer properties of a GeoJSON polygon layer in Leaflet

Tags: python, leaflet, geojson, folium

In a Leaflet GeoJSON polygon layer, I want a popup information box, showing attributes of each of the polygon properties. So the final output should show the Country Name, Area, Population etc properties accessed from the GeoJSON layer of the particular polygon; something like the image.

[image: GeoJSON layer popup example]

For this reason what should I write inside Popup?

```
gj = folium.GeoJson(open("country.geojson",encoding = "utf-8-sig").read())
popup = folium.Popup('Country name: ')
popup.add_to(gj)
gj.add_to(map)
```

Comment: Maybe this can get you going in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171687/adding-a-popup-to-a-geojson-layer-in-folium

Comment: I tried to write a code following that post as you directed but all I get is the message "'GeoJson' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Since I have 0 experience with Folium and no environment to try it, I'm afraid I can't help you here.

Answer (score 1):

In Leaflet you can use the option `onEachFeature` from the `L.GeoJSON` class to declare a function for each layer in the GeoJSON.

Here is a example on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guihig/5j0n7wm8/9/

Note that I used a previous made GeoJSON dataset from this link: https://github.com/datasets/geo-countries/blob/master/data/countries.geojson

Comment: This syntax does not work in Folium.